# How to extends Java static fields in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a Java file

```
public class Code {
    public static final int SUCCESS = 0;
    public static final int FAIL = 1;
}
```

I created a kotlin class that extends the Code class.

```
object ResponseCode : Code() {
    val SKU_STOCK_NOT_ENOUGH = 2000
}
```

I cannot call the statement, ResponseCode.SUCCESS, in other Kotlin function.
What can I do to make kotlin class extend the Code class's static field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin, unlike Java, static members are not inherited by subclasses, though they can be called inside a subclass without specifying the base class name.

For this case, you can either call using the base class. Or:

```
object ResponseCode : Code() {
     val SKU_STOCK_NOT_ENOUGH = 2000
     val _SUCCESS = SUCCESS

}
```

One more option is declaring a method instead of a variable.

```
object ResponseCode : Code() {
    val SKU_STOCK_NOT_ENOUGH = 2000

    fun SUCCESS(): Int {
        return SUCCESS
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to get static field from java class https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#accessing-static-members

only way:

```
object ResponseCode : Code() {
    val SKU_STOCK_NOT_ENOUGH = 2000

    fun getSuccess() = SUCCESS
    fun getFail() = FAIL

}
```